# Android ImageButton scale down on press

Tags: android

I want to add an `ImageButton` to my layout that has the effect of scaling down in order to look like it's being pressed. So I basically have the original image `@drawable/scan` and the pressed image which is `@drawable/scanhot`. Scanhot is basically the same image **scaled down**.

My code is the following but it doesnt seem to work.

As you can see I am using a `Button` as opposed to an `ImageButton` because a `Button` could at least "switch" different images. However it does not do anything with similar images like scan/scanhot

**button_rescan.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/scanhot"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/scan"/>
</selector>
```

**layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_radar_rescan_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_rescan"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: your button_rescan.xml only contains the selector block right?

Comment: yes, that is correct :)

Comment: and you've confirmed the dimensions of both images? scanhot is in fact widthXheight < scan's widthXheight

Comment: yes, scan is 132x29 and scanhot is 120x26. Not much of a difference but the "animation" should be noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with what you are doing is that when you set a picture to a background, it automatically is blown up to fit the `View`.  Instead, both pictures should have the same resolution, but the picture in scanhot should just *look* smaller.

In otherwords, both pictures should have a 132x29 resolution (or rather, they should both be the same size)

Answer (score 2):

It looks that `drawable/scanhot` are not the same size `drawable/scan` (in pixels). So if you want effect of "zoom" (or whatever) you should still keep **image size** the same for both images (i.e. 100x100) and with the same size make `scanhot` look smaller. If you already got images scalled as you want, just load the smaller one to Gimp or Photoshop and scale its `canvas` to the size of the other image (which is bigger I assume) and then save. In that case canvas for both will be the same and you avoid additional scalling from ImageView

Comment: Yes that is intended. I want once "scan" is pressed for "scanhot" to appear in order for it to seem like it is "pressed".